# How subdivide or not layout for display one or two button depending on switch state?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, view, screen

I develop a screen of an Android application in Kotlin). I am looking for a good practice and an example to display one or two buttons depending on the status of a switch.

If the Switch is disabled, I would like display a single button that takes the entire width of the screen (match parent).
If the switch is activated I would like two buttons to be displayed on the same line with a width of 50% each.

How to set up such a structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ConstraintLayout` and `match_constraint` (0dp) on both of them as below. Note the use of the spread chain style and the constraints.

By setting the visibility as `GONE` on one button, you'll see the other will take the whole width. You can test it in the layout editor by using `tools:visibility="gone"` alternatively.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/button_left_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonRight"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topElement" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/button_right_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topElement" />
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! thank you !